# Ordenar numeros float en Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ordenamiento

Mi objetivo es ordenar un archivo cars.csv. Concretamente quiero ordenar una de las columnas donde se encuentran los siguientes números:

```
8.0
8.5
23.4
7.5
7.3
8.50
```

He utilizado el sort con la opción -g y -n pero ninguna parece funcionar correctamente.

Cuando utilizo `sort -n` me deja el 8.50 al final de todo cuando 23.4 es mayor que 8.50. Y cuando utilizo la comanda `sort -g` el 8.50 queda ordenado pero los demás no.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿En qué versión de sort lo pruebas? A mí `LC_ALL=C sort -n fichero` y sin locales me funciona bien

Comment: FUNCIONA! Mil gracias! No conocía LC_ALL=C. En qué consiste este comando? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que `sort` utiliza el separador de decimales que tengas por defecto en tu sistema. Si por ejemplo tienes el italiano, pues es diferente del inglés.

La solución es definir un "locale" que te convenga. En este sentido, `LC_ALL=C` es la más simple y te ayuda:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -n fichero
```

Ejemplos:

```
$ printf "1.123\n7.3\n23.50\n8.70" | LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8 sort -n
7.3
8.70
1.123
23.50
$ printf "1.123\n7.3\n23.50\n8.70" | LC_ALL=C sort -n
1.123
7.3
8.70
23.50
```

Más info en [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/40596) <sub>en inglés</sub>, muy completa.